# Custom weblogic application SSO authentication

Tags: java, weblogic, single-sign-on, kerberos, oracle-adf

Can anybody describe me how to use single sign-on SAML authentication in my weblogic application?

I can't use default SSO configuration because I need to do some custom checks before authenticate user. Now I use custom form auth:

```
    public String login() {
    //Some my checks...

    HttpServletRequest request =
        (HttpServletRequest)((ServletRequest)ADFContext.getCurrent().getEnvironment().getRequest());
    CallbackHandler handler =
        new SimpleCallbackHandler(username, password);

    Subject subject;
    try {
        subject = Authentication.login(handler);
        ServletAuthentication.runAs(subject, request);
        ServletAuthentication.generateNewSessionID(request);
    } catch (LoginException e) {
        handleException(e, "Введен некорректный логин или пароль");
        return "fail";
    }
    //Some other checks
    return "success"
}
```

I would like to write something like this:

```
    public String login() {
    if (isSSOEnabled) {
         //DO SOMETHING TO USE SSO
    } else {
         //do form-based auth
    }
}
```

I use weblogic 10.3.6 and AD with Kerberos.